# OneSignal for iOS on PhoneGap does not register devices

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-build, onesignal

Since `OneSignal` updated its code and functions, I am not able to to register any iOS 10 devices.

I use `PhoneGap` build with version (cli-6.1.0)

It works fine for Android and the devices get registered.

Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am sure that something with your certificates, just try to make an **Ad Hoc** provision profile to match your **distribution** notification profile you may have entered based on instructions of OneSignal. Also faced the same problem when trying to install app with development certificate an mobile provision.